# Symbolic Integration Using Trapezoidal Rule in Matlab

Tags: matlab, symbolic-math

I want to symbolically integration a function using trapezoidal rule. The problem is I do not want the final expression of how the integration looks like. I want all the steps.

For example, for a function

```
function y = myfun(x, y)
y = 2*x+y.^2;
```

integrated from t = 0 to t = 2, with a time step of t = 0.5 using trapezoidal rule, I want the summation expression for each time step:

```
t = 0.0 to t = 0.5 
t = 0.5 to t = 1.0   
t = 1.0 to t = 1.5
t = 1.5 to t = 2.0
```

Because I want to see what is happening at each summand.

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by wanting to do this symbolically? The trapezoidal rule is, by its very nature, a *numerical* method... Please show the desired output

Comment: its the trapezoidal rule. You just do trapezoids. Every steps is simple, and repetitive. If you want each step, its probably easier to just do it by hand.

Comment: @wolfie I have added a picture of the desired output. Can you advise now, please?

Comment: So when you say symbolic representation you mean you want to build up a string of what the result should be comprised of, or something with actual [symbolic variables](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/sym.html)? I mean this seems a pretty redundant task, since the trap. rule is so easy to express by hand, and more appropriate to express using summation notation... not sure what you're looking to do with this result?